# Can I take the "derivative" of a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Due to how we're defining a random sample, the distribution on my hands takes the approximate form of a cumulative density function (CDF) of a normal distribution.  Knowing that a CDF is the integral of a normal distribution, is there any way to recover the normal distribution *from* the CDF? ie what would amount to differentiating the CDF.

Edit: Updated PDF to CDF

Comment: "...PDF is the integral of a normal distribution..." Do you mean the CDF?

Comment: Sure, take the derivative of the PDF. It's calculus. You know how to do the chain rule. I think you want to take the derivative of the CDF, and that's really how a density is defined.

Comment: When you say "the distribution on my hands" --- are you talking about a sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A density is *defined* as the derivative of a CDF. Why this is the case won't make sense when you think about nice distributions like the normal distribution, since we all know the $e^{-x^2/2}$ expression that gives a bell curve, but it does make sense in a more advanced treatment of probability that uses measure theory to unify many types of distributions.

So yes, the derivative of the CDF of the normal distribution is the PDF of the normal distribution. Try it out for a distribution density that has an integral (CDF) you can calculate, such as exponential. Then you can play with calculus and take the derivative to recover the PDF.

Comment: I've come across this a few months later and want to point out that, while the gist of this is correct, the technical details are not quite right when you use measure theory and work in a general probability space.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing that a PDF is the integral of a normal distribution, is there any way to recover the normal distribution from the PDF?

This doesn't make sense to me.  A PDF is the derivative of a CDF, and the normal distribution isn't recoverable from any old PDF.

To answer the titular question, the PDF is just a function, so assuming it is differentiable (I think most are, though it's been a while since analysis for me) then yes you can differentiate it.